# Call Action class from JSP page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I'm trying to hit my action class from my JSP via button click to refresh the `textarea`. In debug mode I am not hitting my action class.

**JSP Page:**

```jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<sj:head/>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

</head>
<body>
    <s:form name="defineFileForm" action="selectDefine">
        <table class="formTable formContent">
            <tbody>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Choose the file type that best describes your data</legend>
                    
                    <label for="defineStartRowline">Start Data Preview at Row:</label>
                    <input id="defineStartRowline"  name="defineStartRowline" size="20" maxlength="50" style="visibility : visible" type="text" value="<s:property value='defineStartRowline'/>"/>
                    <input type="button" value="Refresh Data Preview" onclick="refreshTextArea()"/>
                    
                </fieldset>
                
                <fieldset>
                <legend>Data Preview</legend>
                
                <textarea rows="30" cols="50" wrap="off" readonly value="<s:property value='defineTextArea'/>"></textarea>
                
                </fieldset>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </s:form>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        
        function refreshTextArea(){
            
            alert('Inside ajax call')
            
            var rowNumber = $('#defineStartRowline').val();
            
            alert(rowNumber)
            
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url: '<s:url namespace="/" action="ajaxRefreshDefineTextArea"/>',
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {'defineStartRowline' : rowNumber},
                success : function(result){
                  if (result != null && result.length > 0){
                    $("defineStartRowline").val() = result.defineStartRowline;
                  }
                },
                error : function(xhr, errmsg) {alert("Nothing found!!");}
            });    
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="fileimport" namespace="/" extends="struts-default, json-default">
      <action name="ajaxRefreshDefineTextArea" 
          class="com.Files.fileimport.FileImportAction" 
          method="loadDefineScreen">
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="root">jsonData</param>
            </result> 
      </action>
        
   </package>
</struts>
```

**Action Class:**

```java
public class FileImportAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware{


private String defineStartRowline;
private String defineTextArea;

public String getDefineStartRowline() {
    return defineStartRowline;
}

public void setDefineStartRowline(String defineStartRowline) {
    this.defineStartRowline = defineStartRowline;
}

public String getDefineTextArea() {
    return defineTextArea;
}

public void setDefineTextArea(String defineTextArea) {
    this.defineTextArea = defineTextArea;
}

public String RefreshDefineTextArea()
{
   String tempRowNumber = defineStartRowline;
   
   if(!tempRowNumber.equals(""))
   {
       defineTextArea = "Hello There m8!";
   }
   
   
   return "success";
 }

}
```

I get the 2 alerts and then I get the `"Nothing found..!!` alert. Any idea what I am missing or over looking?

Comment: It looks like you don't understand how things work. Take your time and read some tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Struts 2 the action is mapped to the method, and in configuration the method `loadDefineScreen` used to map the action, but it's absent in the action class.

There are errors in the javascript, json object returned by the Struts is not an array, so it has no `length` attribute. The `root` parameter in result is invalid, and to get the property of the action you need to remove this parameter or use `#action` value. This parameter is used by default.

```xml
<result name="success" type="json"/>
```

jQuery [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function without argument cannot be used to set the value to the element. Check the correct syntax on the reference site.

Answer (score 0):

your url shoud be only

`url: 'ajaxRefreshDefineTextArea',`

```
<script language="JavaScript">

        function refreshTextArea(){

            alert('Inside ajax call')

            var rowNumber = $('#defineStartRowline').val();

            alert(rowNumber)

            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url: "ajaxRefreshDefineTextArea",
                dataType : 'json',
                data : {'defineStartRowline' : rowNumber},
                success : function(result){
                  if (result != null && result.length > 0){
                    $("defineStartRowline").val() = result.defineStartRowline;
                  }
                },
                error : function(xhr, errmsg) {alert("Nothing found!!");}
            });    
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: NO. The single correct point in OP is using `<s:url>` for url construction.

Comment: url: 'ajaxRefreshDefineTextArea', will work I am using same way

Comment: It **may** work but using `<s:url>` tag for url construction is way better.

Comment: It isn't a direct url. OP has so much wrong/odd things and you suggest that single correct thing should be changed to something not so good.